# Radio Button Position CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style this radio buttons for gender choice as shown in the image below:

[image]

```css
.radio {
  margin: 0.1rem;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  margin-top:
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]+.radio-label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.9em;
  height: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
  /* position */
  top: -3.4em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked+.radio-label:before {
  background-color: #3197EE;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #f4f4f4;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:focus+.radio-label:before {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #3197EE;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+.radio-label:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #f4f4f4;
  border-color: #b4b4b4;
  background: #b4b4b4;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]+.radio-label:empty:before {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <p>Sex <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="sex" id="ville" data-rule="required" data-msg="Vérifiez votre saisie sur les champs : Le champ 'Ville' doit être renseigné." />
  <div class="validation"></div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input id="radio-1" name="radio" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-label">Male</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <input id="radio-2" name="radio" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the Male and Female label to be in the right position, which is beside the respective buttons, however adding an ID to the label tag wouldn't allow me to do so.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: I've stopped short of tagging it for you, but if you're using Twitter Bootstrap framework, please tag as such.

Comment: @esqew added, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Remember to consider non binary gender

Comment: @ryanve will do, this is just for test haha

Comment: @rwd Lemme know if that's what you expect. Look at my answer. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried a bit of swap. I got till this:

```css
.radio {
  margin: 0.1rem;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  margin-top:
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.radio input[type="radio"] + .radio-label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.9em;
  height: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
  /* position */
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: -2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-label:before {
  background-color: #3197EE;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #f4f4f4;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:focus + .radio-label:before {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #3197EE;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled + .radio-label:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #f4f4f4;
  border-color: #b4b4b4;
  background: #b4b4b4;
}
.radio input[type="radio"] + .radio-label:empty:before {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="form-group">
  <p class="d-inline-block align-top">Sex <span>*</span></p>
  <span class="icon-case"><i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i></span>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <div class="radio">
      <input id="radio-1" name="radio" type="radio" checked />
      <label for="radio-1" class="radio-label">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input id="radio-2" name="radio" type="radio" />
      <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="validation"></div>
  <input type="text" name="sex" id="ville" data-rule="required" data-msg="Vérifiez votre saisie sur les champs : Le champ 'Ville' doit être renseigné." />
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Changes**

A bit of change in CSS:

[image: changes]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! So I tried to adjust my css according to your code, but it seems like there is some misalignment with the current styling I have. I will post a screenshot to show you

Comment: added screenshot. That's the problem I'm having now

Comment: @rwd How do you want? Can you tell me what you want?

Comment: Something like the one you have. But your css styling doesn't seem to apply to my current one, which is why mine is showing that way in the screenshot